# markdown adjust the column size and add a break line between rows

Tags: css, markdown

I am using

```
| title | details |
|-------|---------|
|today is sunday| today is 2014-01-01|
|tmr is monday| today is 2014-01-02|
```

Weird thing is, it seems that the first column has a fix width. When the text length is greater than the width, it will break the text into two rows.

Like in this example: 
it show

```
|today is|
|sunday  |
```

rather than

`|today is sunday|` in the same row.

Can anyone tell me where I could change the width of the first column and add a border between first row and second row? (add a solid line between)

```
 |today is sunday| today is 2014-01-01|
 |tmr is monday| today is 2014-01-02|
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define a fixed width to a column in a table, the text inside will wrap if it is too large to fit horizontally.

If you want the table to size itself to the largest element of the row, then remove the fixed column width.

In CSS you can't give tr's border properties so you will need to set "border-bottom: 1px solid black;" to each td element of that row.

I suggest you post some code if you want help fixing it.

Comment: I found there is one way to do it by using non-breakable space today&nbsp;is&nbsp;sunday, this will make the first column wider, however, this works in some online markdown viewer but on in my project, in my project, it would appear "&nbsp;" rather than a space. Do you have any idea what library should I import besides markdown itself? Thanks for your reply